# Why the solution for $1+y^{\prime}(x)^{2}-y(x) y^{\prime \prime}(x)=0$ is $y(x)=C_{1} \cosh \frac{x-\mathrm{C}_{2}}{C_{1}}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $$1+y^{\prime}(x)^{2}-y(x) y^{\prime \prime}(x)=0$$
I don't understand how this is the solution for this differential equation. where $C_{1,2}$ are constants of boundary condition.

I substitude $$y(x)=Ae^x + Be^-x$$

and than I got $$AB=\frac{1}{4}$$ and than I concluded that $$A=B=\frac{1}{2}$$ thus the solution is just $$y(x)=cosh(x)$$
what I did wrong that I have no constants, and also why the solution $$y(x)=Ae^x + Be^-x$$ is work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation is separable,
$$
\frac{2y'y''}{1+y'^2}=\frac{2y'}{y}
$$
After that first integration you should be able to continue to solve the resulting first-order autonomous equation.

---

With your approach, you fixed too much arbitrarily. At least you should get $A=\frac12e^c$, $B=\frac12e^{-c}$ to get the solutions $y(x)=\cosh(x+c)$ that are to be expected for an autonomous equation. Then you could have a negative sign in both of the coefficients.

But your trial solution is too restrictive, note that the given equation is not linear, so in general you can not expect to get exponential solutions.

Comment: how does this kind of differential equation is called? I guess I need to read about it some information

Comment: It is just some autonomous second order differential equation, related to the [brachistochrone problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve). There may be some helpful structure from being related to an Euler-Lagrange equation. In general you can try the "trick" $y'=u(y)$, that is, taking $y$ as new parameter on non-constant solutions, and then inserting with $y''=u'(y)y'=u'u$. This is not really changing the problem, only making the possible transformations more obvious. Any simple solution you obtain with the trick you can also produce without.